# DocX table, how to set the header background colour?

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I am creating a word document using DocX.
I want to put in a background colour for a table row.
I can't find how to do it:

```
var text = string.Format("{0}. {1}", SectionNo, section);
var headerTable = Doc.AddTable(1, 1);
headerTable.SetWidths(new float[] {600});
headerTable.Design = TableDesign.LightList;
var para = headerTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First();
para.Append(text);
Doc.InsertTable(headerTable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it,

```
tbl.Design = TableDesign.TableGrid
```

using the TableGrid is just a grid but there are some styles  in here that may be of use. I found them all ugly as hell.

The other way would be doing it at the cell level which I have found to be the better way of doing it.

```
tbl.Rows[0].Cells[0].FillColor = Color.FromName("Red")
```

The only caveat with this is that you may need to change your font colour too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was using my VB code on this one, forgot to change it C#

Comment: Also, you could use Color.Red insted of Color.FromName("Red"). And for me I had to specify that this is a System.Drawing.Color, because if I just put Color, it picks System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: i guess because Im using ReSharper it automatically brings things in for me most of the time so i forget about things like that